# doctrine how to write WhereIn() with another sql query inside

Tags: sql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

i have the folowing query in SQL

```
... where group_id IN (select group_id from alert where monitor_id = 4);
```

I want to write it in Doctrine but i don't know how to add the IN select into WHEREIN() clause !
any idea ?

this is what i did

```
$q = $this->createQuery('u') 
    ->select('u.email_address') 
    ->distinct(true)
    // ->from('sf_guard_user u') 
    ->innerJoin('u.sfGuardUserGroup ug') 
    ->where('ug.group_id IN(select group_id from alert where monitor_id=?',$monitor);     

$q->execute();
```

In the sfGuardUserTable.class:

```
public function getMailsByMonitor($monitor) {


        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from("alert a")->where("a.monitor_id", $monitor);
        $groups_raw = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
        $groups = array();
        print_r($groups_raw);
        foreach ($groups_raw as $gr) {
            $groups[] = $gr->id; //line 33
        }


        $q2 = $this->createQuery('u')
                ->select('u.email_address')
                ->distinct(true)
                ->innerJoin('u.sfGuardUserGroup ug')
                ->whereIn("ug.group_id", $groups);
        return $q2->execute();
    }
```

Comment: not related to the actual question but to the use of this query: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Do you use Symfony-1.4 with Doctrine 1.2 or are you using Symfony2 with doctrine2? (confusing tags)

Comment: Symfony-1.4 with Doctrine 1.2

Comment: Are that `// before `->from('sf_guard_user u')` relevant?

Comment: @SymFoNyBegginer: Consider rewritting the query using `JOIN` or even better with `WHERE EXISTS` than with `IN`. MySQL's execution plan for `x IN (SELECT y FROM z)` is known to be not optimal. It's not very bad if your tables are small (in number of records) but if they are big you'll notice difference in speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you would do something like:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('User u')
  ->whereIn('u.id', array(1, 2, 3));
```

But I think this one better fits your needs:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('Foo f')
  ->where('f.group_id IN (SELECT f.group_id FROM Alert a WHERE a.monitor_id = ?)', 4);
```

Comment: why do you select a.grou p_id from alert (make sure there is no space inbetween).

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in y
our SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version f
or the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: would it be possible to add the relating schema.yml part to your question and your current dql query?

Comment: that's the peace of query:
->where('ug.group_id IN(select group_id from alert  where monitor_id=?',$monitor);

Comment: $q = $this->createQuery('u')
                ->select('u.email_address')
                ->distinct(true)
               // ->from('sf_guard_user u')
                ->innerJoin('u.sfGuardUserGroup ug')
                ->where('ug.group_id IN(select group_id from alert  where monitor_id=?',$monitor);
        $q->execute();

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution - fetch  `select group_id from alert where monitor_id = 4` into an array and use it in `whereIn`

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from("alert a")->where("a.monitor_id", 4);
$groups_raw = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
$groups = array();
foreach ($groups_raw as $gr){
    $groups[] = $gr->id;
}

$q2 = Doctrine_Query::create()->from("table t")->whereIn("t.group_id", $groups);
```

Two queries instead of one, but definitely do the trick.

Comment: i don't realy understand your query !

Comment: The idea: fetch all group ids into an array with first query, than use this array in `whereIn` in second query to retrieve the final result.

Comment: i get this error :
c:\Dev\sfMonitoring>symfony monitorsRetreive
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Dev\sfMonitoring\lib\mod
el\doctrine\sfDoctrineGuardPlugin\sfGuardUserTable.class.php on line 33

Comment: this is line 33:
 $groups[] = $gr->id;

Comment: That means nothing to me. I don't have your code here, could you update the question with the code that produces this error (and please, don't forget to mark line 33 :)

Comment: Ah, my fault :) Change `HYDRATE_ARRAY` to `HYDRATE_OBJECT` **or** `$gr->id` to `$gr['id']`.

Comment: Unknown record property / related component "id" on "Alert"
any ideaaaas ??

Comment: Well, that was your homework, I think your `Group` table have index column named `group_id` :)

Comment: Replace `$gr->id` with `$gr->group_id`

Comment: it seems that this code bloks the computer! the process is taking more than 5minutes and still not finished yet !