# use wherenotIn clause in doctrine with another query inside

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to use where not In clause in doctrine

I did it like this:

```
$q->select('u.id')
->add('from', $from)
->Join('Entities\User','u','with','evt_vstr.user = u.id')
->where('evt_vstr.event = ?1')
->andwhere('u.designation= ?2')
->andwhere('u.id notIN (SELECT sender FROM Entities\Connect)')
ORTHIS  ->andwhereNotIn('i.id',$connect_id)  
->setParameter(1,$content['event_id'])
->setParameter(2,$content['designation'])
->setFirstResult($i)
->setMaxResults($max_result);
```

but its throw an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException' with message 'SELECT u.id FROM Entities\\EventVisitor evt_vstr INNER JOIN Entities\\User u WITH evt_vstr.user = u.id WHERE evt_vstr.event = ?1 AND u.designation= ?2 AND u.id notIN ('SELECT sender FROM Entities\\Connect')'
```

and when I write this as follow

```
->andwhereNotIn('u.id', array(1,2,3,4,5)')
```

then it gives the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Doctrine\\ORM\\QueryBuilder::andwhereNotIn()
```

I read this here: [doctrine how to write WhereIn() with another sql query inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203086/doctrine-how-to-write-wherein-with-another-sql-query-inside)

How can I do that ?

[sjagr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188035/sjagr), [Yann Eugoné](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4067211/yann-eugon%C3%A9)

Comment: Have a look at this http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html. **IN() Expression**

Comment: Try `not IN` instead of `notIN`.

Comment: I found nothing about IN or NOT IN here [smarber](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1507546/smarber)

Comment: i tried this also  ->andwhereNotIn('u.id',$connect_id) saying undefined  methode

Comment: Go to http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html, then `CTRL-F` and type `IN() Expression`

Comment: yes it is but its in simple sql query not using createqueryBuilder() [smarber](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1507546/smarber)      like this     SELECT u FROM CmsUser u WHERE u.id IN (1, 2)

Comment: You need use EXPRESSION in your DQL then Doctrine will catch `expr()->notIn($x, $y)`; furthermore, for the second `SELECT` you need to get a separate DQL by using queryBuilder then you need to use it as second param as `->notIn($x, $DQL)`. Take a look at http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class for more info

Comment: there is a description about whereNotIN() something like Convenience/proxy method for whereNotIn().   at http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/doctrine/1_2/en/06-Working-With-Data  .      what does it mean ? i am unable to find anything about this [Javad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3348750/javad),[smarber](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1507546/smarber)